# Hashmap inside hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am creating a key value pair hirarchy for World->country->state->cities using map.
List of cities stored in states and states are stores in Map(country). Now I want to store this map(country) in anather map(country) having list of two different countries. How can I implement it.

```
List<String> mh=new ArrayList<>();
mh.add("Pune");
mh.add("Mumbai");


List<String> mp=new ArrayList<>();
mh.add("Bhopal");
mh.add("Indore");

Map<String, List<String>> india= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
india.put("Maharashtra",mh);
india.put("Madhyapradesh", mp);

List<String> al=new ArrayList<>();
mh.add("bostan");
mh.add("newyork");

List<String> fl=new ArrayList<>();
mh.add("tahapilee");
mh.add("antophill");

Map<String, List<String>> america= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
india.put("Alaska",al);
india.put("florida", fl);

Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> world= new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
world.put("a", america);
world.put("b", india);
Set<String> keys= world.keySet();
```

Comment: You're modelling your problem in a very unhelpful way. Create classes for concepts like Country, State, City and the interfaces will organically start to appear. Make `State` contain a `List<City>`, `Country` contain `List<State>` etc. Either way: *what is your question?*

Comment: As @kryger said, try to create models that represents the problem, if you work with collections inside collections inside collections, you will end up with a very confusing code.

Comment: Ok..Thanks..I will do it.